# WhereBetween function in not working properly Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5

```
$dt = \Carbon::now();
$tomorrow = Carbon::tomorrow();
$yesterday = Carbon::yesterday();
$data = $this->model->select('id', 'description')
 ->whereBetween($dt, array($yesterday, $tomorrow))->get();
```

It is returning an error saying "**An error occurred in database operation.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `wherebetween` clause the first argument should be table column field, which you are trying to compare. 
For example:

```
$data = $this->model->select('id', 'description')
 ->whereBetween('created_date', array($yesterday, $tomorrow))->get();
```

Comment: One more.
Can I pass the column fields in the array?

Comment: No. You can not pass the array of column fields in whereBetween  clause.